# Is it possible to create a re-usable function with the PostgreSQL plv8 extension?

Tags: postgresql, plv8

I wanted to drop in google's open location code javascript implementation into PostgreSQL (using the [plv8 extension](https://pgxn.org/dist/plv8/doc/plv8.html)) and make it available to encode/decode from PostGIS geometry/geography data types.

While I was successful, I wasn't able to work out how to only create a single function for the https://github.com/google/open-location-code/blob/master/js/src/openlocationcode.js file and I ended up putting a copy of that function into each function where I needed to encode/decode plus codes. When I attempted to pull it out into its own function,  I could either get a string containing javascript or a string of [Object],[object] rather than a callable function.

Is this possible with the plv8 extension in PostgreSQL?

Incomplete code snippet example ([full version here](https://github.com/cumminsjp/open-location-code/tree/postgis/postgis)):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS olc.encode(float,float,integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION olc.encode(
    p_latitude double precision,
    p_longitude double precision,
    p_code_length integer DEFAULT 10
)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$


 var f  =  function () {
    var OpenLocationCode = {};

    /**
     * Provides a normal precision code, approximately 14x14 meters.
     * @const {number}
     */
    OpenLocationCode.CODE_PRECISION_NORMAL = 10;

    /**
     * Provides an extra precision code, approximately 2x3 meters.
     * @const {number}
     */
    OpenLocationCode.CODE_PRECISION_EXTRA = 11;

    // A separator used to break the code into two parts to aid memorability.
    var SEPARATOR_ = '+';

    // The number of characters to place before the separator.
    var SEPARATOR_POSITION_ = 8;

    // The character used to pad codes.
    var PADDING_CHARACTER_ = '0';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Store the source code of the function in a special database table and load it using `select` and `eval()`. Read about details in this answer: [Can plv8 JavaScript language extension call 3rd party libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45131867/1995738)
2. Place the function in an initialization module and set this module using configuration parameter `plv8.start_proc` so it is executed automatically on start-up. You can find details in [the PL/v8 documentation.](https://github.com/plv8/plv8/blob/master/doc/plv8.md#start-up-procedure)

The second option is really handy and does not need an additional table, but may seem a bit tricky. A simple example: we want to have a function `square_of_sum(a, b)` predefined in all our plv8 functions. First, create the initialization function:

```
create or replace function plv8_init()
returns void language plv8 as $$

    square_of_sum = function(a, b) {
        return (a+ b)* (a+ b)
    }

$$;
```

set the initialization function for the database:

```
alter database my_database set plv8.start_proc to plv8_init;
```

and close the current connection.

In all subsequent sessions the function `square_of_sum(a, b)` is known in every other plv8 function, e.g.:

```
create or replace function js_test()
returns int language plv8 as $$
    return square_of_sum(3, 2)
$$;

select js_test();

 js_test
---------
      25
(1 row)
```

Comment: I already up-voted that other question and forgot to circle back to it. 
 But that (select+eval) works perfectly. Thanks!